# How to enable warnings for unused params/pattern variables in Purescript?

Tags: compiler-warnings, purescript

For example, we have code like

```
render metadata sysDefView enabledFeatures state =
  hundreds of_ lines of_ code here using metadata enabledFeatures and state
```

I would like to get a warning that `sysDefView` is not used, so that I would know to either use it, remove it, or replace it with a `_` pattern as appropriate.

Comment: I don't think PS has such warnings currently. Consider contributing to the compiler? :-)

Answer (score 1):

As of yet the compiler can't provide these warnings. There's an issue for it here: https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/1670